# Reducing the font size of the placeholder text without affecting the font size of the input text

Tags: visualforce, javascript, css

In a visualforce page, how can it be ensured that the placeholder text is smaller than the actual text size of the inputField? My code is as follows:

```
<apex:inputText value="{!subscriptionNumber}" styleClass="subscriptionNumberInput" id="subscriptionNumberInput" onmouseover="checkFindSubsFieldNotEmpty();" html-placeholder="This is 8 digits long and found on letters and emails we send you"/>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`::placeholder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder) pseduo-class:

```
<style>
.subscriptionNumberInput::placeholder {
  font-size: 50%;
}
</style>
```